# Why does this loop produce undefined?

Tags: javascript

Why is there an 11th iteration, and why is 'undefined' printed during it?

```
var num = 10;
var start = 0;
function x(){
    while (start <= num){
        console.log(start + '<br>');
        start++;
    }
}
console.log(x());
```

Comment: 0 ... 10 is 11 iterations

Comment: you're right... i meant 12th

Comment: there isn't a 12th iteration

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because x() does not return anything when you console.log() it.

```js
var num = 10;
var start = 0;
function x(){
    while (start <= num){
        console.log(start);
        start++;
    }
}
x();
```

If you return something in that function then it will output the return.

```js
var num = 10;
var start = 0;
function x(){
    while (start <= num){
        console.log(start);
        start++;
    }
  return 'END';
}
console.log(x());
```

Now the function returns 'END'.

Comment: What if we were to display numbers 0 to 9 only? *return start* displays up to 11, and *return num* displays 10 twice. Confused :/

Answer (score 3):

The function `x` doesn't return a value -- hence the `undefined` part.  There are 11 iterations counting from 0 to 10 since the condition is `start <= 10`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the function `x` does not return anything and you are `console.log`-ing its output.

Answer (score 0):

Because x() does not have a return value, and there are 11 iterations between 0 and 10. If you change `start <= num` to `start < num` you would only have 10 iterations. Also, instead of logging x(), you can just execute it by itself, which will run teh code and log the 10 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

All functions in javascript which do not have a return statement, returns `undefined` by default.

Comment: Perfect answer! Now I know why :) Thanks